# Is it possible to edit lightning:inputField ui attributes via recordUi?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-recordeditform

I need to make the `Name` field required on the `lightning:recordEditForm`. So I tried its `onload` event and `recordUi` parameter. But it didn't work. So I am wondering if it's even possible with `recordUi`?

component.cmp

```
<lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="myObject__c" onload="{! c.handleOnload }" >
    <lightning:inputField aura:id="field" fieldName="Name" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

controller.js

```
handleOnload: function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log("handleOnload");
    const recordUi = event.getParam("recordUi");

    recordUi.objectInfos["myObject__c"].fields.Name.required = true;
    recordUi.objectInfo.fields.Name.required = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you cannot set the lighting:inputField ui to required.  You can however update the CSS file and add the customRequired class to the field and it will mark it as required,  I then handle the submit event and check to see if the required fields have been filled in

## CSS

```
.THIS .customRequired{
    font-weight: 400; 
 } 

 .THIS .customRequired:before{    
     content: "*";
     margin: 0 0.125rem 0 0.125rem;
     color: rgb(194, 57, 52);
     float: left; 
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, that's possible. But event with this approach user will not see the error text "Complete this field." under the input field as they generally get for required fields. I'd like to find some way that would give consistent behavior. See it at http://i.imgur.com/n0u1MFw.png

Comment: Also [HTML 5 required attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#The_required_attribute) won't be showed as well